# Android didn't open open activity by url scheme if the app launch already

Tags: android, url-scheme

I have StartActivity and MainActivity, in manifest scheme is already set.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myApp" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
```

StartActivity:

```
public class StartActivity extends InstrumentedActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        if (isLogin) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The original design is after user pressed the url in browser, it open StartActivity and then go to MainActivity when user logined.

This works correctly in the first time (App is killed and user pressed the url). 
But while the app is in the background (in MainActivity), after user press the url, it didn't go through StartActivity but only onResume of MainActivity.

Anyone know the reason? and how to make sure it go to StartActivity? Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code of StartActivity

Answer (score 1):

when you open your Activity first time from URL ,that time Activity  created so `onCreate()` method called .But if your Activity is in Background then 
`onNewIntent()` will be called so Override this method And put you code here .

Add below method : IN MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // add your code here 

}
```

In Manifest :

```
<activity
 android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 />
```

Start Activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

if you want pass any input value then you may pass in Intent through Bundle ,that is received into `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` ,and you can get just like we get data from Intent send from one Activity to next activity.

Comment: Checked by using debugger, onNewIntent is not called in MainActivity

Comment: I think you have removed   android:launchMode="singleTask" ,Thats why it did not called.

Comment: if you are using   android:launchMode="singleTask" in Manifest do not need to add Intent Flags in StartActivity

Comment: Sorry my mistake, android:launchMode="singleTask" is in my code, just isn't included in this post